# Replacing hardwired dishwasher with existing wire

Tags: wiring, kitchens, dishwasher

I am replacing one Frigidaire gallery dishwasher with an new one. My old dishwasher only  had a black and white wires for hardwiring. So it was wired black to black and white to white with the power supply and the bare copper grounded to the frame.  My new dishwasher has black white and a green wire. I connected black to black and white to white. Do I hook the green from the washer to the bare copper from the power supply or do I hook the green to the the green terminal connected to the frame and then ground the copper to the frame [image][image][image]

Comment: Can you *please* post a photo showing the box/wires you are trying to connect the dishwasher *to*?

Answer (score 2):

The green wire is the same as the bare copper.
The green or bare copper is the equipment grounding conductor and it should be tied to the frame.
Connect the green wire to the bare copper in the box should be connected to the frame by a green grounding screw.  Tried to phrase it both ways but green or bare from the supply to the machine doesn't matter the connection to the system ground and to the frame is the important part.